# How many combinations to pick r objects from 2n objects (1 ... 2n) when repetition is allowed so that all odd objects appear the same # of times

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that the total number of combinations, in other words selections where no repetition is allowed, in this case would be ${2n+r-1\choose r}$, but im not sure about how I would include the scenarios where the odd numbers appear the same amount of times. Probably by taking the complement of this and subtracting it? But not sure what that would look like.

Comment: Do you know if $r$ is even or odd?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose each of the $n$ odd objects is chosen $k$ times.  Then you must choose $r-nk$ even objects with repetition from the $n$ even objects, so the total is
$$\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n+r-nk-1}{r-nk}$$